# Custom Extensions on Managed Chromebooks

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps, google-chrome-app, chromebook

I am a developer looking for the best way to set up **different schools with their own custom, private extensions** (ie School A should be the only one with access to Extension A). Theoretically, I am aware that there are a few ways to get a custom, private extension pushed out on a domain:

1. **Host the .crx** on a server and click "Specify a Custom App" in the management console.
2. **Create a Domain App** by uploading a zip to the Chrome Web Store
3. Upload the extension from my developer account to the Chrome Web Store and publish to a single **"trusted tester,"** or make it **unlisted**

**Option (1)**, hosting the .crx, has not been working. I am not sure why, but the extension is simply not pushing out. I link directly to the crx file, which has the right ID and MIME type, still, no dice. If anyone has any tips or suggestions for getting this to work, I would love to hear them!

**Option (2)**, having the school create a domain app, seems a bit inefficient because it requires all schools to upload their own zip. So essentially I would have to email a zip file to the school, and have them publish it. All updates to the extension will also require a similar process, so this doesn't seem ideal.

I doubt that **option (3)** would work. If I published to the admin as a "trusted tester", I don't think that the other people in the domain would be able to access it. If it is unlisted, I do not know how an admin could find it in the Chrome Web Store dialog. Also, I would rather avoid security through obscurity.

Has anyone had success with hosting the extension and using the **Specify a Custom App** feature? Any other suggestions for getting a Custom Extension pushed out by the management console? Thanks so much!

Comment: When you say that option one is not working, is it just downloading the extension instead?

Comment: Exactly, it will load up in the console (just by displaying the extension ID) but then not download on the chromebooks. We have waited a while, too.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read the question well enough, I had not realized that it was a management console. I have not used it before, but I do know that for .crx files not from the WebStore, you have to download them, then drag them into the browser to install them. If you are able to get a single custom app that deploys to all of the schools, might it be possible to have some local server that ID's the school and has the app choose which functionality to expose. Save that as a setting in the app for when away from the school. (This may be a lot more work than it is worth.)

Comment: Yeah, I do not think that is possible.  I am not sure how one could reliably ID the school without user interaction.

Comment: You would have to have some local server with a consistent IP or hostname. It would attempt to contact the server for a single file that contains json data about what school it is. This would work as long as it connects to the school network. Like I said, a lot of work.

Comment: That is very clever! However the extension needs to figure out what school it belongs to even when it is not on the school network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get option (1) working from the management console, it is important to specify the correct extension id and a valid update xml url (not a crx).

One useful feature Google offers that you can use is getting the extension id and the version from the update request.

For instance, you can create a update.php file that outputs an xml file specific to each extension and version.  See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html under "Advanced Usage".

For more info on packaging an app or extension for managed chromebooks, see https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=en.