# Pushing Custom Extension from Personal Domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-apps, google-chrome-app, chromebook

I've built a custom chrome extension that I'd like to be pushed out to managed devices via a private URL that I have. Currently I can access my URL from the browser `http://myurl.com/extension/<app_id>` and I get prompted to download the CRX file that I have, so it seems as though the server is responding correctly.

However, when I add the custom extensions' settings into the managed console fields that I need (for ID I input the apps ID, and for URL I'd have `http://myurl.com/extension`), it doesn't seem to send the app to the chromebook.  I've tested sending store apps to the chromebook, which works, so I'm curious if maybe I'm skipping some important step to get my custom app pushing from my custom domain.

Comment: I think you have a wrong URL. It needs to be an update XML instead of a link to the CRX. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614018/custom-extensions-on-managed-chromebooks?rq=1

Comment: I added an update XML linking to the CRX instead, but it's not making a difference.